# Drawing more than one object to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I try to draw 2D objects in the same JFrame panel.

I wrote such a code, but to be honest, it doesn't work as I expected, I guess while adding the second object, it destroyed the previous one.

I was looking for the solution, but I couldn't find out anything :(

Is there anyone who can help me?

```
        public class Demo1 {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Demo1();
            }
    
        public Demo1() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    TestPane objA = new TestPane(200, 300);
                    TestPane objB = new TestPane();
                    
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(objA);
                    frame.add(objB);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    
        public class TestPane extends JPanel {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int h = 0;
    
            public TestPane(int xa, int ya) {
                x = xa;
                y = ya;
            }
    
            public TestPane() {}
    
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 800);
            }
    
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int width = x;
                int height = y;
    
                if ((x == 0) && (y == 0)) {
                    width = getWidth();
                    height = getHeight();
                }
    
                g2d.setColor(new Color(139, 69, 19));
                g2d.fillRect((width / 2) - 20, height / 2, 40, height / 2);
    
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                int radius = 60;
                g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - radius, (height / 2) - (radius * 2), radius * 2, radius * 2);
                g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - radius, (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
                g2d.fillOval((width / 2) - (radius * 2), (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
                g2d.fillOval((width / 2), (height / 2) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:
After those modifications, it works
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

```
            JPanel mainframe = new JPanel();

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainframe.add(objA);
            mainframe.add(objB);
            frame.getContentPane().add(mainframe);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is what user15358848 wrote. If you add it directly to a JFrame, they end up in CENTER, which can take only one component.

If you want to have more than one component in the CENTER area, just nest them in a JPanel (basically in everything derived from Container, but JPanel or subclasses is the most reasonable) and add that JPanel to the CENTER area.
Make sure to add a Layout to it, that matches your needs, so that e.g. the two Components are side by side each other or on top of each other.
The Default Layout for JPanel is FlowLayout. You can change it with setLayout(LayoutManager).
You should be able to find a lot of complete examples for that on the web, with those keywords. JFC / Swing offers lots of possibilities. Have fun!